# Opening gnumeric with pandas lib

Tags: python, excel, pandas, gnumeric

I tried to run a simple xlsx file and open it with gnumeric.

The code:

```
python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

The code runs correctly and indeed when I open it via Excel I am able to see the data. On the other hand, when opening with gnumeric, it fails with message:

> Unsupported file format.

I did try to open an xlsx file not from the Python and gnumeric opened it correctly.

I don't know where the problem could be.

On an other note, is there another way to save a multiple sheet gnumeric file from Python without using pandas ExcelWriter?

Answer (score 0):

XlsxWriter files should work without any issue in Gnumeric. They are essentially 100% the same as Excel files.

I ran your sample code and was able to open the file in Gnumeric:

[image]

**Versions**:

- gnumeric: 1.12.35
- xlsxwriter: 1.2.8
- os: ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This is interesting. can you tell me what is the version of gnumeric you are using? maybe the problem lies there..

Comment: I've added the versions but I doubt that is the issue. I've been using gnumeric for years and have never seen that issue. And also, as I said, an xlsxwriter file like the one produced above is almost 100% the same as one produced by Excel. Could you check if the file is corrupted in some way. For example like this: `unzip -l pandas_simple.xlsx` on the same system as gnumeric.

Comment: This is what I got:
Archive:  pandas_simple.xlsx
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
     1091  04-26-20 08:10   xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
      550  04-26-20 08:10   xl/workbook.xml
      179  04-26-20 08:10   xl/sharedStrings.xml
      784  04-26-20 08:10   docProps/app.xml
      592  04-26-20 08:10   docProps/core.xml
     1167  04-26-20 08:10   [Content_Types].xml
     1341  04-26-20 08:10   xl/styles.xml
     6994  04-26-20 08:10   xl/theme/theme1.xml
      587  04-26-20 08:10   _rels/.rels
      697  04-26-20 08:10   xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels

Comment: Also, I tried to look what formats I could save in and they are as follows:
Comma separated values (CSV) ,
Data Interchange Format(*.dif) ,
Gnumeric XML (*.gnumeric) ,
HTML (*.html) fragment ,
HTML 3.2 (*.html) ,
HTML 4.0 (*.html) ,
LaTeX 2e (*.tex) ,
MS Excel (tm) 5.0/95 ,
MS Excel (tm) 97/2000/XP ,
MS Excel (tm) 97/2000/XP & 5.0/95 ,
OpenOffice OASIS_UNFINISHED_ ,
TROFF ,
Text export (configurable) ,
XHTML (*.html) ,

Comment: What version of Gnumeric are you using?

Comment: Gnumeric 1.10.17